# Nginx configuration for rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

So I have this configuration at the moment in nginx:

```
autoindex off;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        location @extensionless-php {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
```

Now, I want to get something 'special'. I want to get an url (`http://project2.local/camera?camera_id=1`) to be rewritten as `http://project2.local/camera/1` I've tried this code;

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/?camera\.php$ /camera/%1? redirect;
}

location /camera {
  rewrite ^/camera/([^/]*)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 break;
}
```

but that downloads something empty when I navigate to that place.. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
location /camera {
    rewrite ^/camera/([^/]*)$ /camera.php?camera_id=$1 last;
}
```

The `rewrite...break` will prevent the `camera.php` URI being processed by the PHP location. You need to use `last` as per your existing configuration. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

You also added: `location / { rewrite ^/?camera\.php$ /camera/%1? redirect; }`, but it seems wrong and superfluous for a number of reasons:

- You cannot have two `location /` blocks (perhaps you meant you added the line of code to the existing `location /` block)
- I do not recognise the `%1` term (the value of the parameter would be `$arg_camera_id`)
- It will never match anything (URIs ending with `.php` are processed by the PHP location)